# character array blanking in c

Tags: c, string, whitespace, scanf

code

```
int main()
{
     int n,m,i,j;char a[10][10];
     printf("enter n and m values\n");     
     scanf("%d%d",&n,&m);

     printf("enter array values");    
     for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        for(j=0;j<m;j++)
          scanf("%c",&a[i][j]);

     printf("the array is \n");
     for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        for(j=0;j<m;j++)
          printf("%d %d %c\t",i,j,a[i][j]);
}
```

Input

```
 Enter n and m values  
 4 5
 Enter characters 
 11111000001111100000
```

Output

```
0 0 

0 1 1   0 2 1   0 3 1   0 4 1   1 0 1   1 1 0   1 2 0   1 3 0   1 4 0   2 0 0    
2 1 1   2 2 1   2 3 1   2 4 1   3 0 1   3 1 0   3 2 0   3 3 0   3 4 0
```

Error

If I give the value of n as 4 and m as 5 ,scanf does it job.

But while printing when the value of i is 0 and j is 0 it does not print anything.

Meanwhile a[0][1] prints the first input and a[0][2] prints second input and consecutively , so last input 0 is missing while printing.

Please explain why a[0][0] is avoided.

Comment: It's likely that there is a return character left in the buffer (because you scanf() only 2 integers) and it's being assigned to [0][0]. Try using `fflush(stdout)` before reading any characters with scanf.

Comment: Second result on google: http://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/caution-when-reading-char-with-scanf-c/

Comment: @sherrellbc I would not expect `fflush(stdout)` to have an effect on `stdin`.

Comment: @chux, of course not. My mistake. It should be `stdin`.

Comment: @sherrellbc; No. [It should not](http://www.c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush.html).

Comment: Hint: always check return value of any `scanf` function. If it's less than what you expect, and you don't handle it, it's not going to end well.

Answer (score 5):

Previous `scanf` calls leave behind `\n` character in the input buffer which goes along with input on pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Return</kbd> key. `scanf("%c",&a[i][j]);` reads that `\n` on first iteration.

You need to flush your input buffer. Either place a space before `%c` in `scanf`

```
scanf(" %c", &a[i][j]);   
       ^A space before `%c` can skip any number of leading white-spaces
```

or you can use

```
int c;
while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
```

---

**NOTE:** [Will `fflush(stdin)` work in this case?](http://www.c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush.html)

> `fflush` is defined only for output streams. Since its definition of "flush" is to complete the writing of buffered characters (not to discard them), discarding unread input would not be an analogous meaning for `fflush` on input streams.

**Suggested reading:** [c-faq 12.18](http://www.c-faq.com/stdio/scanfc.html).

Comment: I looked at the documentation for scanf and it ignores any whitespace until the `format` (being a char in this case) is read in. What exactly does the space do?

Comment: @sherrellbc "ignores any whitespace until the format" is not correct.  The precise function of `scanf()` is lengthy.  Note: `"%c"`, `"%n"`, `"%[]"` do not skip leading white-space.

Comment: @chux, ah, my mistake. I read it assuming it would skip white space, but you must first include the whitespace character (as haacks does above) to trigger this feature.

Comment: Should be noted (not that you made this suggestion) that `fflush` should only be used on output streams (e.g. not `stdin`).